# Blender 2.8 (python) - automated UV map variation to avoid look-alike cubes

Tags: python, uv

I have a script in python that creates a lot of cubes to which I would like to apply a texture.

Thus far I have done the UV mapping with smart project, mostly because I have been intimidated by the prospect of having to figure out how to write the python script that would map coordinate by coordinate.

My concern is that smart project will map the cubes the same way every time as opposed to creating variation.

My question - what is the most efficient way for me to vary the mapping of each cube?

Thanks!

Comment: You can prob do this via the node editor. If they all use the same material, you can offset the uv mapping node using the Random socket of the geometry node. (naming of the nodes could be wrong, I’m on my phone)

Comment: how would one do that?  I have mostly used smart project thus far and am a complete novice when it comes to UVmapping at the node level.